# How can I calculate the critical t-values of a linear regression model?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, linear-model

I have implemented a linear regression in R (lm) and would like to show the significance and direction of the coefficient by means of the t-value. But now I'm not sure how to compute the critical t-value which makes the coefficient significant.

Comment: Critical t-values are mostly a concept of the past. Students are still taught them because they are not allowed to use a computer during exams and have to used t-tables. In practice, you use software to calculate a p-value (or, preferably, a confidence interval). Since you are using software, you should calculate p-values and, in fact, the `summary` function calculates them for you.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree, but in this case I need to make an exception and present the results solely based on the t-values, which is why I need the critical values.

Comment: So? Just calculate them. See `help("qt")`.

Comment: So like this qt(.975, 200), if I want the 0.05 significance and have 200 degrees of freedom? I though the standard error must be part of it?

Comment: You need the standard error to calculate t-values. Critical t-values are calculated from the distribution. No standard error needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to construe the question as meaning: What is the t-statistic and what is its probability distribution?

You have

\begin{align}
Y_i = {} & \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i \quad \text{for } i=1,\ldots,n \\[10pt]
& \varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_n \sim \operatorname{iid} \operatorname N(0,\sigma^2). \\[10pt]
\widehat\beta_1 = {} & \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\overline Y)(x_i-\overline x)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x)^2} \\[10pt]
& \text{where } \overline Y = (Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)/n, \\
& \text{ and } \overline x = (x_1 + \cdots + x_n)/n. \\[10pt]
\text{and } \overline Y = {} & \widehat\beta_0 + \widehat\beta_1 \overline x. \quad (\text{This defines } \widehat\beta_0.) \\[10pt]
\widehat{\varepsilon\,}_i = {} & Y_i -\left( \widehat\beta_0 + \widehat\beta_1 x_i \right).
\end{align}
Then

- $\widehat\beta_1 \sim \operatorname N\left( \beta_1, \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x)^2} \right)$
- $\dfrac{\widehat{\varepsilon\,}_1^2 + \cdots + \widehat{\varepsilon\,}_n^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-2}.$
- $\widehat\beta_1$ and $\widehat\sigma^2 = \dfrac{\widehat{\varepsilon\,}_1^2 + \cdots + \widehat{\varepsilon\,}_n^2}{n-2}$ are independent.

From these it follows that
$$
\frac{\widehat\beta_1 - \beta_1}{\widehat\sigma/\sqrt{n-2}} \sim t_{n-2}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\widehat\beta_1 \pm A \frac{\widehat\sigma}{\sqrt n}
$$
are the endpoints of a confidence interval for $\beta_1,$ where $A$ is a suitable percentage point of the $t_{n-2}$ distribution.

Here I have not included proofs of the points following the three typographical bullets above. Possibly proofs of those have been posted here before.

Answer (score 1):

That answer by [Michael Hardy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/5176/michael-hardy) gives you the formulae for manual calculation for simple linear regression.  Since you have implemented your model in `R` the easiest thing would be just to generate the outputs using standard commands in that program:

```
#Fit a linear regression model
#Substitute the actual names of your data frame and variables
MODEL <- lm(y ~ x1 + ... + xm, data = DATA);

#Print structure of model
str(MODEL);

#Print summary output
summary(MODEL);

#Print ANOVA table
anova(MODEL);

#Generate studentised residuals
RESID <- resid(MODEL);
```

The `summary` table in the `R` output contains the coefficient estimates table, which includes the t-statistics and associated p-values for each of the terms in the model.

Comment: Many thanks, I agree that the summary table provides enough information for the significance. However, I need to present the results only with the t-values and thus I need the critical values. How can I do this particularly in R?

Comment: Try ```summary(MODEL)```.